# How do I deploy keycloak docker container on Azure?

Tags: azure, docker, keycloak, azure-appservice

I am attempting to deploy jboss/keycloak docker container from Docker Hub onto an Azure App Service.

However, after I start up the service and visit the URL, it just loads infinitely.

I am starting the docker container with "docker run jboss/keycloak".  I have also tried adding in "-p 80" and "-p 80:80" to no avail.

Here is my app service config:
[image]

Comment: You do not need to input anything for the Startup File. Just let it empty.

Answer (score 2):

Removed "docker run jboss/keycloak" and it worked!

Comment: Hi, how did you create the admin user at the first run? I am trying to connect to the container through SSH but with no success.

Comment: Create the following environment variables from (Configuration->Application Settings->New Application setting):

KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD  

KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD  

PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING => set this to true