# Keycloak not booting on Azure container apps

Tags: azure, keycloak, azure-container-apps

I am trying to boot Keycloak with start-dev on an azure container apps, and it's not working.

My configuration is the following :

[image: aca config]

I have no application logs in `ContainerAppConsoleLogs_CL`

I only have the following system logs : `Container 'key' was terminated with exit code '' and reason 'ContainerCreateFailure'`

[image: error log]

I tried with a previous version of key cloak: 16.0 seems to work, but not the latest (24)

Do you any insight on how I can debug further?

Comment: Similar thread- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224582/how-do-i-deploy-keycloak-docker-container-on-azure

Comment: Remove thet start dev and try, since it's a prebuilt quay image it should be already packaged with the image, seperately not required. Also did you try to run this quay keycloak locally? working? alternatively you can try jboss/keycloak

Comment: jboss/keycloak should not be used as this repo is not updated any more and it has version 16 as latest. Keycloak is distributed through quay.io now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue with v24.0.1. Once I changed the command to: `/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh, start-dev`

The path of `kc.sh` is the same as found in the `Entrypoint` in the image. The comma is required to separate between argument and command (as I followed the help text in the form field).

Answer (score 0):

To setup keycloak on ACI using image stored in ACR you can follow below steps-

Create an ACR if you don't have one:

```
az acr create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myRegistry --sku Basic
```

once active enable admin login from portal in your acr or using CLI

```
az acr update --name myRegistry --admin-enabled true
```

login to acr

```
az acr login --name myRegistry
```

Push the Keycloak image to ACR
I am using jboss image

```
docker pull jboss/keycloak![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/SoDPlaT.png)
docker tag jboss/keycloak myRegistry.azurecr.io/keycloak
docker push myRegistry.azurecr.io/keycloak
```

**Create a Container App**

- Go to the Azure portal, and create a new Container App.
- Select the appropriate subscription, resource group, and region.
- Choose the ACR as the source for your container images.
- Select the `myRegistry.azurecr.io/keycloak` image you pushed earlier.
- Set up the required environment variables for Keycloak, such as `KEYCLOAK_USER` and `KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD` while setup. Configure the CPU, memory, and other network setting and deploy
  [image]

Once deployed, you can verify the same using the app url

[image]

**Other alternative methods**-
Using azure webapp

Here , I am using the same jboss/keycloak image in my acr and create the webapp. When setting up, select docker container
[image]

and under docker tab choose your acr where you kept the keycloak image

[image]

[image]

You don't have to put any startup command. Choose your type of networking and deploy

[image]

and similar way you can access your keycloak using the app url
[image]

**Alternatively if you use quay keycloak**, as suggested by Marc Schneider, while setup under command section, you can use command: `/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh, start-dev` and it should boot up
also I added the keycloak credentials as environmental variable

`KEYCLOAK_USER = admin`
`KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD = Password`

and was successfully able to deploy keycloak on azure container apps

[image]

[image]

Reference:
Keycloak on
[keycloak on webapp](https://alonewolf24.medium.com/how-to-deploy-keycloak-in-azure-app-services-in-docker-f13da34b92e6)